# Conexão cliente-servidor via socket

Tags: java, android, socket, cliente-servidor

Preciso fazer uma conexão via socket da seguinte forma:

O meu aplicativo Android tem um botão "Confirmar" - quando clicar no botão ele tem que enviar uma mensagem para o servidor e depois disso o servidor tem que retornar uma mensagem para o meu aplicativo informando "dados cadastrados com sucesso!".

Porém ele não está fazendo a conexão com o servidor. O que há de errado?

> Android Manifest XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.isadoraoliveira.testeapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.isadoraoliveira.testeapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String hostname = "localhost";
    private static final int portaServidor = 6789;
    Socket socket = null;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

            new Thread(new Runnable()){

            @Override
                public void run (){

            try {
            socket = new Socket(hostname, portaServidor);

            //dados enviados para o servidor
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                        bw.write("Dados enviados para o servidor");
                        bw.newLine();
                        bw.flush();

            //dados reebidos pelo servidor
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        System.out.println("Dados cadastrados " + br.readLine()); //retornar ok

            socket.close();
                    }
                    catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }

            });.start();

                }
            });


    }
}
```

> ServidorSocket.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ServidorSocket
{
   private static int portaServidor = 6789;

   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception{

      ServerSocket ServerSocket = null;
      ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(portaServidor);

      while(true){

            System.out.println("Servidor iniciado!");
            Socket socket = ServerSocket.accept();

            //recebe mensagem do cliente - mensagem vai ser passada por meio do botão android
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("Mensagem do cliente " + br.readLine()); // ok

            //envia mensagem para o cliente - talvez não precise
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            bw.write("Dados cadastrados com sucesso!");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();


      }
   }
}
```

Comment: NetworkingOnMainThreadException, ele está dando este erro???? Pois conexões assim não são permitidas, nem mesmo em Runnable na thread da UI. Teria que criar uma asynctask para poder fazer este tipo de chamada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que fazer toda chamada de internet fora da thread da UI, mesmo que seja dentro de um Runnable como fez, a thread ainda continua sendo da  UI. Vou colocar dois blocos de código para ilustrar uma solução:

CommAsyncTask.java, onde eu crio a tarefa em background:

```
package com.grupoestudos.myapplication;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CommAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private static final String hostname = "localhost";
    private static final int portaServidor = 6789;
    private IAsyncHandler mHandler;

    public CommAsyncTask(IAsyncHandler mHandler) {
        this.mHandler = mHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, portaServidor);

            //dados enviados para o servidor
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

            //Estou usando Arrays.toString(), somente para ele pegar todas as strings que passar no
            //método.
            bw.write(Arrays.toString(params));
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();

            //dados reebidos pelo servidor
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String retorno =  "Dados cadastrados " + br.readLine(); //retornar ok
            socket.close();

            return retorno;
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Aqui você utiliza o retorno do doInBackground
        //Aqui é interessante usar um EventBus, ou alguma outra classe para poder enviar essa
        //informação para a interface.
        mHandler.postResult(result);
    }
}
```

E a MainActivity.java, onde você vai fazer a chamada e aproveitar o resultado:

```
package com.grupoestudos.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IAsyncHandler{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Cria a tarefa para ser executada em background
        CommAsyncTask task = new CommAsyncTask(MainActivity.this);

        //Aqui eu chamo a execução. Como é em background, por isso citei de usar um EventBus ou outra
        //forma de poder recuperar a informação. Não é a melhor forma, mas de forma ilustrativa, vou
        //criar um método para receber a informação e aproveitar na activity.
        task.execute("Dados enviados para o servidor");
    }

    @Override
    public void postResult(String result) {
        //Neste método você pega o resultado da asynctask e aproveita de alguma forma
    }
}

interface IAsyncHandler {
    void postResult(String result);
}
```

Dá uma olhada neste guia que ele ajuda:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sending-and-Receiving-Data-with-Sockets

Comment: Você pode dar um exemplo de como fazer isso? Links externos são bons para trazer referências e outras informações - mas a solução deveria estar disponível aqui, por completo (links podem ser alterados ou simplesmente deixar de existir).

Comment: Editei a resposta com um trecho de código

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, esclareceu algumas dúvidas que estava tendo. Obrigada!

Comment: Qual lib vem esse "IAsynchandler"?

Answer (score -1):

Eu estabeleço a conexão diferente do que você fez:

//imports:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
```

//codigo:

```
SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(sockaddr, timeout);

if(socket.isConnected()){
//se estiver conectado eu deu um write e o read
}
```

Comment: Você pode explicar melhor por que o código dela não funciona, e por que a sua alteração vai corrigir o problema?